# Ошибка в Jackson сustom Serializers/Deserializers

Tags: android, java

Для того, что бы разобраться с сustom Serializers/Deserializers вынес в отдельный проект, выдает вот такую ошибку:

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(288): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not create generator for non-byte-based target

[image]

Файлы программы:

MyActivity.java

```
 package com.example;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import com.example.JacksonObject;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
 import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonGenerationException;
 import java.io.IOException;

 public class MyActivity extends Activity
{
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);        


    String jacksonString = "{\"DateField\":\"/Date(61283424600000)/\",\"StringField\":\"STRING_string\",\"DoubleField\":\"87.12345\",\"IntegerField\":\"387\"}";
    try {
        MyJsonWrapper sss = new MyJsonWrapper();

        JacksonObject[] mailItems2 = sss.getMyJson().readValue(jacksonString, JacksonObject[].class);
        int a2 = 3;  //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
        int  b = a2; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!


    }   catch (JsonGenerationException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (JsonMappingException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    int a = 3; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
    int s = 10; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
    s = s + a; //это просто так, что бы поставить точки!!!
}
}
```

JacksonObject.java

```
package com.example;

import java.util.Date;

public class JacksonObject
{
public Date DateField;
public String StringField;
public Double DoubleField;
public int IntegerField;
}
```

MyJsonWrapper.java

```
package com.example;


import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParser;
import org.codehaus.jackson.Version;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.module.SimpleModule;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonDeserializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.smile.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.*;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ser.std.NullSerializer;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.*;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.lang.reflect.Type;
import java.util.Date;


public class MyJsonWrapper
{

public ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());        
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());        

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

public class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{


    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {

        String s = jp.getText().replace("/Date(", "").replace(")/", "");

        if (s.equals("")) return null;

        boolean isDateBefore1970 = false;

        ............................................

        if (isDateBefore1970)
            return new Date(-Long.valueOf(s) - offset * 60 * 1000);
        else
            return new Date(Long.valueOf(s) + offset * 60 * 1000);

        }catch (JsonMappingException e){
            // If a JSON Mapping occurs, simply returning null instead of blocking things
            return null;
        }


    }
}


public class JsonDateSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Date>
{
    public void serialize(Date date, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {            
        jgen.writeString("/Date(" + date.getTime() + ")/");
    }
}    
}
```

а если в MyJsonWrapper.java использовать static вместо public

```
public class MyJsonWrapper
{
public static ObjectMapper getMyJson()
{        
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());        
    SimpleModule module = new SimpleModule("MyModule", new Version(1, 0, 0, null));

    module.addSerializer(Date.class, new JsonDateSerializer());
    module.addDeserializer(Date.class, new JsonDateDeserializer());        

    mapper.registerModule(module);

    return mapper;
}

static class JsonDateDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<Date>
{


    public Date deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext context) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        try {
```

то выдает такую ошибку

ERROR/AndroidRuntime(314): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.MyActivity}: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can not create generator for ......

[image]

Вот эта строка

JacksonObject[] mailItems2 = sss.getMyJson().readValue(jacksonString, JacksonObject[].class);

Comment: Строка №91 в MyActivity.java где находится? Ткни пальцем, тогда будет хоть что-то понятно.

Comment: Спс, вынес строку

Comment: Надо отлаживать по уму - так с налету на скажешь. Начните со сноса своего custom сериалайзера даты, поставьте брекпойнты, обложите логами. Попробуйте сериализовать и посмотрите какая JSon строка формируется. Такое ощущение что дело не в кастомном сериалайзере, а просто тупо в том, что какое байтовое значение не парсится правильно. То есть какое-то значение воспринимается не как строка, а как число или наоборот число воспринимается как строка из-за чего и валится десериализация.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ошибка была здесь:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper(new SmileFactory());
```

Нужно так:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
```